# Where to start with developing a WordPress / WooCommerce theme?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I've been handed some PSDs and need to create an ecommerce site using WordPress and WooCommerce. I've found a couple of resources for creating WordPress themes...
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/

...but because I'm going to be using WooCommerce, do I still need to follow those guides, or will the WooCommerce development stage make the above guides redundant?

I have researched this, but the resources I've found do not make it clear where to start if you are new to both WordPress and WooCommerce.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to develop a WordPress theme as normal, preferably as a child theme using a good-quality parent theme like [Toolbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox) which will provide most of the html and functionality leaving you to customize the CSS.

Then install WooCommerce and add to you theme from there. In the settings, uncheck the "use WooCommerce styles" and copy the woocommerce stylesheet into your theme folder under `/woocommerce/store.css`. Then you are free to edit the default woocommerce styles as you please.

Comment: Thanks for this. Had a quick look at Toolbox and it looks very appealing. Would it be a lot easier/simpler to use Toolbox than Twenty Twelve as the parent theme?

Comment: Just wondering what the benefits/advantages would be before I dive into it...

Comment: To anyone coming across this that is new to WordPress/WooCommerce, I've now developed a number of WooCommerce sites and now I usually develop with the Canvas theme which is also created by WooThemes: http://www.woothemes.com/products/canvas/

Answer (score 0):

I've created a few themes (not wootheme compatible) in the past, but lately, I'm finding amazing themes with themeforest's offerings
I was always worried about personalization and making my sites look distinct, but that's not an issue, 
Every theme is so configurable in a multitude of layouts/colors etc..
If you search by woocommerce tag you'll find a bunch of themes compatible 
http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress/ecommerce/woocommerce

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. http://themeforest.net/item/bazar-shop-multipurpose-ecommerce-theme/3895788?sso?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=Sara_p seems to be very popular. Would the idea be to install this theme, and create a child theme which I would then modify? The PSDs I've got to develop from are pretty simple, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't it be easier for me just to extend the Twenty Twelve theme, then just add the Woo Commerce functionality - or is that not a good way to go about it?